# Replace NA in a dataframe, keeping the column value distribution

Tags: r, replace, na

### The question

I have a dataframe (~15000 rows, 90 columns) with columns that contain NA's. Here on SO I found multiple Q&A's about filling a NA with values from another df, or from a normal distribution. But these answers will destroy the present distribution in the columns themselfs. Example:

| Person_ID | Var1 | Var2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | NA |
| B | NA | 2 |
| C | 2 | NA |
| D | 1 | 4 |
| E | 1 | 3 |
| F | 1 | 1 |
| G | NA | NA |
| H | NA | 1 |
| I | 2 | 2 |
| J | 1 | NA |
| K | 1 | 3 |
| L | NA | 4 |

The column of Var1 has  a distribution of 75% (1) and 25% (2). One NA should be replaced with a "2" and the others with a "1". Var2 has four values all 25%, one NA each should be replaced with one of the values. The real dataframe is larger in which each column has a  *finite* number of unique numeric values. The real data consists of healthcare information and may not be shared externally.

### Reason for the question

the goal is to perform a t-SNE on the dataframe, so a kNN imputation must be performed. The imputation will take more time then a replace for a quick look at the result. The answer would make it possible to take a quick look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R you could do:

```
set.seed(5)  
data.frame(lapply(df,\(x)replace(x,is.na(x),sample(na.omit(x),sum(is.na(x))))))

   Person_ID Var1 Var2
1          A    1    3
2          B    1    2
3          C    2    1
4          D    1    4
5          E    1    3
6          F    1    1
7          G    1    3
8          H    1    1
9          I    2    2
10         J    1    1
11         K    1    3
12         L    2    4
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to maintain the proportions of the values, in addition to the suggestion by [@onyambu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8380272/onyambu), it would be advisable to include the probability of the values while generating a sample.

```
df[,-1] <- data.frame(apply(df[,-1], 
                            2, 
                            function(x) 
                              replace(x, is.na(x),
                                      sample(sort(unique(na.omit(x))), 
                                             sum(is.na(x)), 
                                             replace = TRUE, 
                                             prob = prop.table(table(x))))))
```

Output:

```
> df
   Person_ID Var1 Var2
1          A    1    4
2          B    1    2
3          C    2    2
4          D    1    4
5          E    1    3
6          F    1    1
7          G    1    3
8          H    1    1
9          I    2    2
10         J    1    4
11         K    1    3
12         L    1    4
```